# Azure Notification Hub register from app backend and app inactivity

Tags: azure, notifications, registration, azure-notificationhub

According to Azure Notification Hub [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-registration-management/#registration-management-from-a-backend), when registering from the app backend, the app provides the backend with its PNS handle.

What if the user does not run the app for a long period? If user does not open the app after some days his handle gets renewed. In that case if I send a push notification user will not receive it?

Comment: Is this a specific problem you are actually experiencing? or you expect to experience?  I think some more context would help people answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's based on platform. Even if App is not opened, you can still send the notifications until the PNS handle expires or invalid.

In case of Android, GCM returns new PNS Handle and if old one expires. And Notification Hub takes care and update the registration.

Thanks,

Sateesh